# Filtering answers by time

Tags: feature-request, sorting

There are answers on SO that acquired a lot of votes during the years but are now deprecated. The reasons for this might be API change, appearance of a new technology...

If a question received a lot of answers, new, relevant answers cannot be seen because the deprecated ones are in the top voted ones.

Additional selection of period for filtering answers would be useful.
E.g. "Sort answers posted in the last 1 month/year by votes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already possible by using [search tricks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching). The search [`inquestion:927358 created:1y..`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=inquestion%3a927358%20created%3a1y..) will return all of the answers posted within the last year for [How to undo the last commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/927358/6083675) (and clicking the votes tab sorts by votes). You can use `inquestion:this` to search for answers on a question you are currently viewing.

Comment: Nice. I am just not sure which percentage of the users is aware of this. I wasn't. 
The other thing is that, for example, a combo box would be more convenient than doing a search trick.